# When should we prefer mvvm cross over mvvm light and vice versa?

Tags: xamarin, mvvm, mvvmcross, mvvm-light

When should we prefer mvvm cross over mvvm light and vice versa ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is really a broad question. I've used both for quite a while.
MVVM Light is probably a little bit more widespread in the community but MVVMCross is a lot better if you plan to develop for iOS and Android. It also has support for async commands, which is one thing that MVVM Light does not unless you add some external libraries.
Unless forced by a customer requirement I definitively prefer MVVMCross and use only it.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks @Antonello for you review. Can you share any example in which we need to add some external libraries ?

Comment: In a recent project I wanted to use async commands and async messages. I ended up using some work from Stephen Cleary https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn630647.aspx and from runceel https://github.com/runceel/AsyncMessenger. I'm planning to put all of this stuff together in a near future, but nothing ready now. This was used to have async network communication and async binding updates triggered by commands on application window

Comment: What about navigation services? Do navigation services vast in MVVM Light as MVVM Cross?

Comment: I've used navigation services in MVVM Light only for very simple applications, can't tell if the services are comparable. For sure navigation in MVVM Cross is better documented and it exposes presenters if you need. Not sure MVVM light has such a feature.

Comment: Thanks @Antonello